# How can I map the amplitude of an ECG signal in relation to the time stamp?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, signal-processing

I'm really new to programming, so can anyone suggest a way to process ECG signals from the MIT-BIH Arrhythmia database that allows me to map the amplitude and time together. Essentially, I want an array that illustrates time as an x value, and amplitude as a y-value. Does anyone have any ideas about how I can go about creating this?

Comment: There's the matplotlib library for instance, but this question seems far too vague and open-ended for StackOverflow. This is a site mainly for getting specific, objective help with code that you're already writing. I think you should ask this on a more appropriate site for general data science questions. Maybe https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ would be better? Or maybe just take some basic Python tutorials that involve graphing and see if you can learn from there. You can't really just jump into a project without a having solid foundation of Python knowledge.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a csv, text, or Excel file? You can load it in using Pandas. Then you can graph it with Matplotlib (or Seaborn which is built off of Matplotlib)

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

signal = np.random.randint(100, size=(1000))
time = np.arange(0,100,0.1)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Signal":signal, "Time":time})
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Time", y="Signal")
plt.title("ECG Signal")
plt.show()
```